# Ruby - Add a class to the puts

Tags: ruby

```
puts sleep(1.5)  && 'ARTHUR: Look! There\'s the old man from scene twenty-four!'
puts sleep(2.5)  && 'BEDEVERE: What is he doing here?'
puts sleep(1.5)  && 'ARTHUR: He is the keeper of the Bridge of Death. He asks each traveller five questions'
```

I want that the arthur part got this:

```
puts sleep(1.5)  && 'ARTHUR'.brown+ ': He is the keeper of the Bridge of Death. He asks each traveller five questions'
```

So it automaticly adds the `'.brown+ '` part

And to the bedevere automaticly adds a `'.red+ '` part

Comment: Text does not have classes. You are thinking of HTML. `puts` knows nothing of HTML. Please add all relevant information to your questions, and tag the question correctly with all pertinent libraries and technologies, and be sure to explain in detail what you want to accomplish. `'ARTHUR'.brown` is an error in plain Ruby without any requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [colorize](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize) gem to apply [ANSI colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for console output:

```
# test.rb
require 'colorize'

puts 'Arthur'.red + ' Look! There\'s the old man from scene twenty-four!'
puts 'Bedevere'.blue + ' What is he doing here?'
puts 'Arthur'.red + ' He is the keeper of the Bridge of Death. He asks each traveller five questions'
```

Output:

[image: iTerm screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You could use ruby [gsub](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) with multiple marchers , replacements:

- The `/ARTHUR|BEDEVERE/` matcher will look for one of the words in an input
- The Hash `'ARTHUR' => 'ARTHUR .brown+', 'BEDEVERE' => 'BEDEVERE .red+'` will be used for replacement

So, it will look like this:

```
phrase1 = "ARTHUR: Look! There\'s the old man from scene twenty-four!"
phrase1.gsub(/ARTHUR|BEDEVERE/,'ARTHUR' => 'ARTHUR .brown+', 'BEDEVERE' => 'BEDEVERE .red+')
# > "ARTHUR .brown+: Look! There's the old man from scene twenty-four!"

phrase2 = "BEDEVERE: What is he doing here?"
phrase1.gsub(/ARTHUR|BEDEVERE/,'ARTHUR' => 'ARTHUR .brown+', 'BEDEVERE' => 'BEDEVERE .red+') 
# > "BEDEVERE .red+: What is he doing here?"
```